# Is the AES key good enough?

Tags: cryptography, base-class-library, system.security

When the `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create(algorithmName)` method is called, a new key and IV are generated. Are these good enough to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those values are safe to use. The whole purpose of frameworks like this one is to make the generation of cryptographically random values easier. `Aes.Create()` is also used in the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Additionally, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_Aes_Create) describes `Aes.Create()`:

> Creates a cryptographic object that is used to perform the symmetric
>   algorithm.

This library is maintained by Microsoft, I think it is safe to say their values are "safe" to use.

Comment: What I am asking is that `Create` generates a `key` that is random enough to be used. I am planning to use a different key/IV for every message.

Comment: Yes those values are safe to use. They are cryptographically generated. If they weren't the entire library would be useless.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft .Net cryptography is generally secure by default, and can be trusted: you should use it rather than trying to generate values your own way.  .Net cryptography is a big step forward from older languages like Java.  I'm planning a blog on the evolution of cryptographic APIs that covers exactly this topic.

Comment: @TheGreatContini That's very opinionated. I think both languages have their advantages and disadvantages. I don't see any reasons for this kind of remark given the topic.